# Data conflicts - Swift

Tags: swift, database, networking, fetch, vpn

I am new to Swift, and I am fetching a VPN certificate from a database to create a tunnel.
The problem is that the variable that should contain the certificate (as Data type) is calling a function that is fetching the certificate, but the certificate takes time to appear, so the variable is empty and sent to the VPN configuration, so the VPN won't work.

The certificate appears later on.

I am not really good at solving these kinds of issues,
I tried to make a delay in the function that is fetching my certificate, but the problem is still present (I know that it's a bad method because network speed may vary and I cannot control the time)

Can you please help me?

```
func getCertificate() -> Data? {
    self.loading.onNext(true)
    var configData:String = ""
    
    Services.getCert(authToken: UserManager.currentUser?.token ?? "", method: vpnMethod, userID: String(UserManager.currentUser?.user_id ?? 0)) { (error, VpnModel, Int) in
        self.loading.onNext(false)
        
        if error == nil{
            if VpnModel?.cert_body == nil{
                configData = ""
            }else{
                configData = VpnModel?.cert_body ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    let configurationData = Data(configData.utf8)
    print(String(decoding: configurationData, as: UTF8.self))
    return configurationData
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a completion as `Services.getCert(......` is asynchronous

```
func getCertificate(completion:@escaping (Data? ->())) {
    self.loading.onNext(true)
    var configData:String = "" 
    Services.getCert(authToken: UserManager.currentUser?.token ?? "", method: vpnMethod, userID: String(UserManager.currentUser?.user_id ?? 0)) { (error, VpnModel, Int) in
      self.loading.onNext(false) 
      if error == nil{
        if VpnModel?.cert_body == nil{
            configData = ""
        }else{
            configData = VpnModel?.cert_body ?? ""
        }
        let configurationData = Data(configData.utf8)
        print(String(decoding: configurationData, as: UTF8.self))
        completion(configurationData)
     }
   } 
}
```

To call

```
getCertificate { res in
  print(res)
}
```